# req.body.title return undefined when retrieving data from React front end using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I keep getting undefined when I try to console.log(req.body.title). Also when I console.log(req.body) I only receive an empty {}.

I am using React for the frontend and express for the backend. The post request is coming from:

```
function handleClick(event) {
event.preventDefault();
const newPost = {
title: input.title,
content: input.content,
};
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/new", newPost).then(console.log(newPost));
}
```

At the server.js this is my post handler

```
app.post("/new", (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body);
});
```

Comment: What's `input`?

Comment: <input
          value={input.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="title"
          name="title"
          autoComplete="off"
        />
        <input
          value={input.content}
          onChange={handleChange}
          placeholder="content"
          name="content"
          autoComplete="off"
        />

Comment: You can [edit] the question and add extra info there. So `input` in question is a local state?

Comment: thanks for the answers. Turns out I dont have a middleware to populate the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I keep getting undefined when I try to console.log(req.body.title).

See [the API reference for request.body](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body):

> By default, it is undefined, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as express.json() or express.urlencoded().

You have no such middleware. You need to set one (which matches the format of the data you are sending - JSON in this case) up as per the examples in that section of the documentation).

Comment: Thank you, express.json() was the solution